# data transfer between two computers in LAN

Tags: windows, networking, data-transfer-objects

I am totally not from the field of networking,
but this work is for my HOME so I need help.

I am having shop for fabrication.
What I need to do is,

when ever customer comes to shop to buy item, 
our sales person get the details of the customer in one file & details of material he required in other file and keep those files in one folder with customer name & date as folder name.

The owner computer (Mine computer) is in other cabin (next room).
Both computers are connected in LAN.

What I need to do is,

At the end of the day,
what all the folders as many they are, must be transferred to my computer (Owner computer).
This computer is having password.
So once the file is transferred to Owner machine then no one will have access to it without permission.
Sales person's computer is not password protected.

How to transfer this folder (on daily basis) from sales computer to Managers computer.
After transferring that folder from sales computer should not have access.

Note :- This should work without internet connection.
I need to have something full shared scenario.
Both machine having windows XP OS

Thanks you for help.
Forgive if I wrong in some where...

Thanks you very much

Comment: Off-topic, SO is about programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following settings can achieve the listed points.

Have pointed sales person as USER A and Owner As USER B

1. User A can able to view/Read User B Folders and files
2. User A can able to create files/Folders on the shared folder
3. User A is not allowed to modify / Delete / Take ownership / Change permission of files or sub folders
4. He is allowed to place folders /files like dropping a letters in a postbox.

to achieve the above points, the following settings need to be done.

1. Create a share folder on USER B
2. Provide only Read, change permission to sales person user account
3. Then go to Security -> Advanced -> change permission -> Click "Add" -> Select sales person user account -> Allow the following permissions -> list folder/read data,read attributes,read extended attributes,create files/write data,create folders/append data,write attributes,write extended attributes -> Click OK -> then Click "Add" -> deny the following permissions - create folders/append data,delete subfolders and files,delete,change permissions,take ownership -> Click OK

that's it.

Check once before proceed further.